# Where can I find documentation for Javascript's `string.replace(RegExp, function)` method?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Javascript has an overload for `string.replace(...)` that takes a Regular Expression and a callback function, but I'm having a very difficult time finding ANY documentation on this specific overload!

W3Schools.com doesn't mention this overload.  I've also gone through dozens of Google results, but every page talks about `string.replace(string, string)` or `string.replace(RegExp, string)`.  It's almost embarrassing not being able to find a solid Javascript documentation reference!  My Google-fu has let me down.

I am mostly interested in knowing everything about the callback function, such as input parameters and return values.  I'm also interested in any possible cross-browser issues.

Comment: It's not a browser-specific extension, then?

Comment: @Scott Waiting for Skyward Sword? `;)`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yep!  Playing through Wind Waker and Twilight Princess right now, in anticipation!

Comment: @todda.speot.is I've used the method many times, and its usage is very common, so I would be very surprised to find out it isn't supported by major browsers.  As SimeVidas points out, it is also mentioned in the ECMAScript specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MDN, of course:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Btw, it's specified in [the ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.11), *duh*.

> If replaceValue is a function, then for each matched substring, call
>   the function with the following m + 3 arguments. Argument 1 is the
>   substring that matched. If searchValue is a regular expression, the
>   next m arguments are all of the captures in the MatchResult (see
>   15.10.2.1). Argument m + 2 is the offset within string where the match occurred, and argument m + 3 is string. The result is a String value
>   derived from the original input by replacing each matched substring
>   with the corresponding return value of the function call, converted to
>   a String if need be.

Comment: Thank you!  I've bookmarked both these references, because I know I'll forget the answer once again.

Comment: The following phrase is awfully generic -- can anyone explain it?  "argument m + 3 is _string_."

Comment: @ScottRippey *string* is the original string upon which the `replace` method is invoked. See chapter "Specifying a function as a parameter" on the MDN page for details about the formal parameters of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

The Mozilla Developer Network has pretty comprehensive Javascript documentation. Including for [`str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[, Non-standard flags]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).